# Appending an element to a specific ID, for loops, and anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, html, append, appendchild

I've created an element node named *figBox* for the *figure* element, setting its *id* attribute to "styleThumbs" and **attempting** to append it to the div element with the id "box".

I then needed to populate the figure box, inserting a for loop with an index that goes from 0 through 4.  In that loop, I wanted to create an img element node named "sheetImg" with a src attribute of "na_small_num.png" and an *alt* attribute value of "na_style_num.css" (where num is the value of the index in the for loop).

Lastly, I needed to have the browser load a different stylesheet when the user clicks one of the thumbnail images by adding an event handler to "sheetImg" that runs an anonymous function changing the *href* attribute of the link element with the ID “fancySheet” to the value of the *alt* attribute of the event target.

Here's what I've already tried:

```
var figure = document.createElement("figBox");
            figure.setAttribute("id", "styleThumbs");
            document.getElementById("box").appendChild(figure);

   for (var i = 0; i = 3; i++) {
   var img = document.createElement("sheetImg");
             img.setAttribute("src", "na_small_num.png");
             img.setAttribute("alt", "na_style_" + [i] + ".css");

sheetImg.onclick = styleElm.seAttribute("href", "alt");
sheetImg.appendChild(figure);
```

The program checking my code is returning this as incorrect which is not surprising considering I'm entirely unexperienced.  Where am I going wrong here?

**EDIT**

Everyone, thank you for your help.  I've figured out the plethora of issues here.  Here is the correct code:

```
var figBox = document.createElement("figure");
             figBox.setAttribute("id", "styleThumbs");
             document.getElementById("box").appendChild(figBox);

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   var sheetImg = document.createElement("img");
                  sheetImg.setAttribute("src", "na_small_" + i + ".png");
                  sheetImg.setAttribute("alt", "na_style_" + i + ".css");
                  sheetImg.onclick = function(e) {
                     document.getElementById("fancySheet").href = e.target.alt;
                  }
                  figBox.appendChild(sheetImg);
}

var thumbStyles = document.createElement("style");
document.head.appendChild(thumbStyles);
```

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i = 3; i++)` less than 3 should be your condition, you"re currently assigning 3 to i

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="na_style_8.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var figure = document.createElement('figBox'),
        loadStylesheet = (stylesheet) => {
            stylesheetElement.setAttribute('href', stylesheet + '?' + new Date().getTime());
        },
        stylesheetElement = document.querySelector('link[href="na_style.css"]');

    figure.setAttribute('id', 'styleThumbs');
    document.getElementById('box').appendChild(figure);

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var sheetImage = document.createElement('sheetImage');
        sheetImage.setAttribute('src', 'na_small_num.png');
        sheetImage.setAttribute('alt', 'na_style_' + [i] + '.css');

        // Populate figBox with created sheetImage
        figure.appendChild(sheetImage);

        // Add click event listener to sheetImg element
        sheetImage.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            // Load stylesheet with anonymous function
            loadStylesheet(event.target.getAttribute('alt'));
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your description, I understood few things check the below code and let me know if anything wrong.

```js
var box = document.createElement('div');
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.setAttribute("href", "defaultStyle.css");
    document.body.appendChild(box);
    document.head.appendChild(link);
    var figBox = document.createElement('figBox');
    figBox.setAttribute("id", "styleThumbs");
    box.appendChild(figBox);

    var linkTag = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(linkTag);
    
    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "na_small_" + i + ".png");
        img.setAttribute("name", "sheetImg");
        img.setAttribute("alt", "na_style_" + i + ".css");
        img.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            link.setAttribute("href", e.srcElement.alt);
            linkTag.innerHTML = link.href;
        });
        figBox.appendChild(img);
    }
```

```css
img {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```